# I am not getting any error nor any output

Tags: powershell

When I type this command in the command line using PowerShell I am not getting any output whatsoever, only a dark blank. Why?

```
Get-Command | Format-Table -Property Application
```

Comment: Evidently `get-command` output rows don't have a property `Application`. Try `get-command | Format-Table -Property name`

Comment: Thank you is working I was wrong Using Application property.